# Histogram - large data set

Tags: plotting, histograms

Hi everyone I have various text files that contain a large number of data points that have a broad range from negative to positive and even numbers that are small on the order of 10^-3 all the way to 10^-8. There are about 100,000 data points per file. The data is all in a single a column and I need to be able to generate a histogram so that I can get a sense of how the values are distributed. How do I go about doing this? Please help me, seriously appreciate any and all insights!

Comment: Can you maybe put a small subset of your data into [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so people can easily try things out?

Comment: data looks something like this:

Comment: -5.56623e-05
-1.4589e-06
-0.0023418396
-0.002966671
-0.0003421337
0.0003824124
-7.525e-07
9.585e-07
-3.736e-07
1.864e-07
-6.165e-07
0.0108392519
0.0142917955
-0.0204017594
-3.78961e-05
1.51851e-05
-0.0247994105
0.0236278443
-0.0002419006
-5.791e-05
-0.0180117059
0.0066504516
-0.012217475
-5.53443e-05
0.0233274161
0.0046151878
2.22565e-05
3.61474e-05
1.06544e-05
0.017932274
5.8896e-05
2.15055e-05
-9.58721e-05
0.0084957179
-2.89584e-05
2.4147e-05
0.0033017166
-0.0030408922
-3.31214e-05
-0.0772874534
-4.8319e-06
0.0002001463

Comment: the actual file contains all of the data but this is essentially what I'm working with

Comment: What is the Import format of your file ? First step would be to correctly import the data in Mathematica with `Import` function for example, then `Histogram` a part of your list to test it.